# Show div on page load - Counteracting toggle function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I searched for an answer on this, but didn't find anything exactly salient to my situation, so posting new question...

I have multiple product category divs on my index page, the contents of which toggle on click, as seen here: [Product Index][1]

Here is basic structure:

**HTML**

```
<div id="bogtoggle">
  <h2>Swatch</h2> 
    <a onClick="toggle(this, 'node<?php echo $row_rsCategories['Category_ID']; ?>')">
      <h2>Category</h2>
        <span>Right-facing toggle arrow</span>
    </a>
  <div id="node<?php echo $row_rsCategories['Category_ID']; ?>">
    ...      
    Contents
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the above HTML pulls on all index pages from an include designated "product-tiles.php".

Here is the script that operates the toggle:

```
function toggle(elm, id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id),
      a = elm.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

  if (e.style.display == 'none')
  {
    e.style.display = '';
    a.innerHTML = 'Down-facing toggle arrow';
  }
  else
  {
    e.style.display = 'none';
    a.innerHTML = 'Right-facing toggle arrow';
  }
}
```

On this general index page, all operates fine. However, I also have index pages individual to the categories: "[Border][2]", "[Panel][3]", "[Tape Edge][4]", etc.. To combat redundancy, I am wanting to use the same HTML to render these pages, rather than go the "easy" route and create new HTML pages for the individual product indexes.

However, for the [individual pages][5], I want to eliminate the toggle altogether and only show my product tiles on page load. How do I go about rewriting the script for these pages to do this?? (Sorry if this is fundamental, still a bit of a Javascript noob.)

Comment: After the creation of the toggle function you could check `document.getElementsByClassName('category').length/2` - if it's 1, then you're on the specific page and you can immediately call `toggle()` using `document.getElementsByClassName('category')[1]` as your first parameter (function would need slight rewrite though, as you currently expect elm to be the `<a>` not the `<h2>`. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Two questions.  1 - What's up with the empty `<h2>` tags?  2 - Is there any connection to jQuery here?  All I see is plain JS.

Comment: Sorry, Surreal Dreams, I edited the <h2> tags. I don't currently have jQuery in the function, but I know that many suggest jQuery solutions.

Comment: Smokey, when you say I should "check" `document.getElementsByClassName('category').length/2`, does that mean to insert it immediately after `function toggle(elm, id) {`?? Also, sorry, I can't make sense of the rest of what you wrote either. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a neat HTML/CSS trick you can use without javascript to use the same HTML page to display different information...
HTML:

```
<a href ="#history">History</a>
```

CSS:

```
#history
{display:none;
}
#history:target
{display:block;
}
```

For better flow and use of your toggle function, simply call it with `<body onload="bogtoggle()">`